# How to find library or other business POIs?

Tags: data, business, point-of-interest, download

I am just starting an Intro GIS course, so I really have no idea what the best place is to find downloadable GIS data.  I was really hoping to do my semester project on *library or bookstore locations* in Southern California, but I am having major trouble finding some kind of library locations GIS file to download.

I'm sure I'm using all the terms incorrectly, but could someone please help? If such a thing does not exist at all, that would also be useful to know.

Comment: Does the "business" tag really fit here?

Comment: @Mary, there are so many similar questions to this, I think if you search our site for questions with the [poi and data tags](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poi+data) and you should find all the data sources you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can get data on specific types of features such as libraries (not necessarly all of them, but at least a good sample) from Open Street Map.

In the case of library, you're looking for things with an [amenity tag of library](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag%3aamenity=library). You can download the OSM data in a lot of ways, but you may find the [Overpass API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) useful. Here is a very simple query you can use:
[http://www.overpass-api.de/api/xapi?*[bbox=-122.5,25.4,-118.5,35][amenity=library]](http://www.overpass-api.de/api/xapi?%2a%5Bbbox=-122.5,25.4,-118.5,35%5D%5Bamenity=library%5D)

Obviously you can modify the bounding box to match whatever you think southern California is.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with some online data at [arcgis.com](http://www.arcgis.com/home/search.html?q=Library&t=content&start=11). 
You should be able to use a national places data set and select the libraries from that.  So you wouldn't necessarily search for libraries but national places database, or gazetteer.